# What is the most elegant piece of code you saw in a lisp

Tags: clojure, scheme, lisp, common-lisp, racket

I try to find good educational tasks which would be preferable to implement in a lisp.

I'm asking not about "good" and "bad" lisp code, but when implementations in other languages would be harder to do / to understand.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on the Clojure mailing list:  clojure@googlegroups.com

Comment: Meta programming. Eg. code that creates code. Now you can still do that in ANY language, but since the syntax of lisp includes making code as data though literals and quasiquote lisp has an advantage. 

DSLs. Basically because you have macros you can improve the language by making new syntax that expresses intent in shorter code and better suited for a certain task. In JavaScript you see they use lambdas for this because macros is just delaying code execution on top of a function.`await`/`async` in JS is just syntax sugar generators and promises and wouldn't need a new version with macros.

Comment: Live programming

Comment: One of the delights of the Clojure community is its refusal to engage in denigrating other languages. Please maintain that positive tone. What drew *me* to lisps was Paul Graham's article ["Beating the Averages"](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html). which sets out the sort of advantages lisp confers in real software development.

Comment: `(define (list . xs) xs)`.

Comment: Search for "metacircular interpreter".

Comment: The bottom half of page 13 in the Lisp 1.5 Programmer's Manual has an implementation of Lisp in Lisp, in two dozen lines or so.